# How to insert radio, checkbox and textbox value in same variable post method name using codigniter?

Tags: php

**my view page**

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>Quiz/add_stu_ans" method="POST"> 
    <label>Who is usa president</label>
    <input type="text" name="answer[]">

    <label>Dhoni is cricket player player</label>
    <input type="radio" name="answer[]" value="True">True
    <input type="radio" name="answer[]" value="False">False

    <label>Which is asian country</lable>
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="newyork">newyork
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="india">india
    <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="srilanka">srilanka

</form>
```

**My controller page**

```
public function add_stu_ans()
    {
     $values['stu_answer']  = $this->input->post('ans');

     $this->Common_model->insert_record('student',$values);
     $this->session->set_flashdata('message_name' , 'Your Data is Inserted');
     redirect('Quiz/question');

  }
```

**And this is model**

```
public function insert_record($table,$values) {     
        $this->db->insert($table,$values);
        return $this->db->insert_id();  
    }
```

*please anyone can tell me how to customize the code in controller*

Comment: `name="answer[]"` is same in all elements, it should be different not same in all elements

Comment: but my table field name is answer so every input values are stored in single columns and multiple rows.

Comment: then change your schema. otherwise how did you know answer for which question ?

Comment: questions are came from question table through loop with qstn_id...and answer table also have a answer id...if answers inserted properly i will compare with both id's then it will be check in boolean method TRUE or FALSE

Comment: @Ameer do you want to make json of the all the data and then save to data?

Comment: @Bhavin Thummar, is this possible to do in json?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: You need to used the json_encode function before save the data array.

Comment: Then you need to use json_decode function applied on data that is fetched from the database.

Comment: can you pls show me some example code to do this...bcos there was multiple inputs to be stored so i dont know how to do..

Comment: ok I will give you in answer.

Comment: ok sir thank you...i will be waiting..

Answer (score 1):

Only possible if you take another hiddent text field where your 'qstn_id' will be in value. take this field in array.

in coding part while taking foreach loop you have to take qstn_id as in "[key]" format otherwise you cant find skipped records.

for eg. :

```
     foreach ($que as $key => $ansValue) {
          $val2 = $ansValue[$key];
      }
// $val2 store as your output.
```

Comment: Thank you but there is also checkbox value how can i split that?

Answer (score 1):

This is code to save the data using json_encode. Let me know you get any error I have not run this code.

> View File

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>Quiz/add_stu_ans" method="POST"> 
    <label>Who is usa president</label>
    <input type="text" name="usa_president">

    <label>Dhoni is cricket player player</label>
    <input type="radio" name="cricket_player" value="True">True
    <input type="radio" name="cricket_player" value="False">False

    <label>Which is asian country</lable>
    <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="newyork">newyork
    <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="india">india
    <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="srilanka">srilanka

</form>
```

> Controller

```
public function add_stu_ans()
    {

     $usa_president = $this->input->post('usa_president');
     $cricket_player= $this->input->post('cricket_player');
     $country= $this->input->post('country');

     $final_data = array(
        'usa_president' => $usa_president,
        'cricket_player' => $cricket_player,
        'country' => $country,
     );

     $json_encode_data = json_encode($final_data);

     $this->Common_model->insert_record('student',$json_encode_data);
     $this->session->set_flashdata('message_name' , 'Your Data is Inserted');
     redirect('Quiz/question');

  }
```

Please check this at your end and time of fetch the data from the database then you need to pass that return data from the function json_decode.

```
$json_decode_data = json_decode($return_data_from_data_table);
```

Comment: Sir thank you...But the questions are also dynamically method...so how can i mention there different post names in different variable?